# Lock up in space plane hangar issue

Tags: kerbal-space-program

When im in the hangar for space planes and have finished creating a plane, I go and press the launch button and the game locks off all of the buttons but still lets me interact with certain parts of the plane (Right click to see fuel etc..). The game stalls in the hangar and doesn't move onto the run way.

Has anyone ever had this happen and if so how have you managed to fix this issue?

P.S. I'm using Version 1.0 of KSP

Comment: You mean the plane doesn't fly? Do you have air intakes on the plane? Jet engines require intake air to fly.

Comment: No, the plane wont even go to the runway. it looks like its stalled in the hangar and wont allow me get to the runway or any other area

Comment: You could try to save the plane, go back to the space center, click the runway and select the saved plane to launch.

Comment: I think this is a bug. Try to save and reload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This exact thing happened to me. The problem seemed to be that my career save was lacking the "SPH" subdirectory to save spaceplane designs.

If you hit Alt/Option - F2, you can bring up the game's console. Within the console log, I saw errors popping up for

> "No such directory:[saves/Career]/ships/SPH"

or something like that.

Once I created that directory in the appropriate place, I was able to save, launch, and load spaceplanes properly. I didn't even have to restart the game.